# Multi-table query with filter using $GET variable in Dreamweaver CS6 recordset

Tags: php, mysql, get, filtering, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a mysql query (using Dreamweaver's recordset feature, that involves 2 tables joined, and filtered using a passed variable it `_$GET`'s from the previous page. Dreamweaver doesn't seem to like me adding the filter when I join multiple tables. (??)

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong as I create this DW recordset ---- Is my concept outdated?

I'm using locations table with primary key `location_id` is equal to the classschedules table with foreign key `location_id`, then filtering the classschedules table to equal a passed variable (in this case int 3 is passed).

Here is the snippet of code:

```
$colname_location_classschedule = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['season_id'])) {
$colname_location_classschedule = $_GET['season_id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_tconn, $tconn);
$query_location_classschedule = sprintf("SELECT * FROM classschedules, locations 
WHERE classschedules.location_id = locations.location_id AND 
classschedules.season_id = %s", 
GetSQLValueString($colname_location_classschedule, "int"));
$location_classschedule = mysql_query($query_location_classschedule, $tconn) or 
die(mysql_error());
$row_location_classschedule = mysql_fetch_assoc($location_classschedule);
$totalRows_location_classschedule = mysql_num_rows($location_classschedule);
```

So the page that is passing the variable passes this:

`(http)//mysite.com/classschd/test.php?season_id=3`

I expected a list of my scheduled classes for all my locations for the particular season (season 3).

Instead, this is the error I get in my browser:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3' at line 1" ----- I don't understand the error message, and I've looked for the answer, and here I am asking.

Any help on any part of this would be helpful to me in the Dreamweaver point of view. I'm using Dreamweaver CS6, php 5.4, mysql 5.5. - Just uploaded most of the programs in Aug2013.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use `text`

```
GetSQLValueString($colname_location_classschedule, "text");
```